# How to add material datepicker to .net webapp?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, datepicker, material-design

How do I add a material datepicker to my asp.net mvc webapp? I tried using HTML.Helpers to create a datepicker, but it looks like this:

[image: What I have]

But I need to look like this:

[image]

Also, I'm using bootstrap. I'm super new, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a dumb question to ask, but I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412775/how-to-add-material-styles-to-asp-net-mvc-web-app). I also have to initials the date picker with this:

```
            <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    var elems = document.querySelector('.IncidentDatepicker');

                    var options = {
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        setDefaultDate: true
                    }
                    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
                });
            </script>
```

This *works*, but it is a bad solution in my eyes. I have partial views that are dynamically loaded every time one is submitted and it doesn't initialize any of them, only the first one.