# How to add material styles to ASP.NET MVC web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, material-ui

How do I add material styles to my asp.net mvc project? I just need to have material checkboxes, switches, datepickers, and inputs with floating labels. I already tried [Material-UI](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1092209/Adding-CSS-UI-Frameworks-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Applicatio) and a few others, but they don't seem to work 100%. I can't get any of the checkboxes and stuff to work.

I "initialized" the matieral-ui in _Layout.cshtml as so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js">
</script>
```

And the styles are applied, but I can't change the default color (Which seems to be green), floating labels are weird, and datepickers still have the native .net appearance.

Labels look like this:

[image]

And date pickers look like this:

[image]

But they both should look like this:

[image]

[image]

Can Material-UI not do this? Is so, how do I do it in ASP.NET MVC?
I'm super new to .NET, so please forgive my naivety if the answer is obvious.

Comment: You are wanting your ui to look like [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), but your are referencing a different ui library in the code sample you provided - [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/). These are 2 different UI libraries! The Material-UI cdn references are [here](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#cdn)

Comment: @zgood Thanks! Isn't that for react, though? Will it still work for .net apps?

Comment: .NET is a server side concept. Picking a client side framework has no bearing on that.

Comment: @mason, But the frontend is HTML and Typescript, not react. How would I implement this in html? https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/#date-time-pickers

Comment: React is a framework, not a language. Anyways it's up to you to pick a library or framework that is suitable for the existing framework that you have. Are you just doing no framework (VanillaJS), Angular, React, Vue? Pick a material theme library suitable for what you're using.

Comment: @mason I am using the bootstrap css framework, but it doesn't include material datepicker. I'm actually trying out materializecss and I seem to have a material datepicker, now, but I can't change the colors. https://materializecss.com/pickers.html Thanks for your help! I'm going to open another question on changing the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best solution I could find is to add [materialize-css](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) via npm and then copy the materialize.min.css and js files into a directory in my wwwroot folder and refrence them both in the _layout.cshtml.